# Accessing webpage for different location using firefox driver in java

Tags: java, proxy, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fetch webpages for different geographical location but every time it redirects me to the local domain.

I am trying to access Expedia's site for Netherlands location ([expedia.com.nl](http://expedia.com.nl)), but it redirects to `co.in` even after setting the proxies.

This is what I do:

```
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "hostname");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "80");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "myUserName");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "myPassword");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://expedia.com");
```

But this lands me to [expedia.co.in](http://expedia.co.in) always. Whats wrong with my approach? Should I try something else?

Comment: The redirection to co.in is done by UI,thr is no any issue with code

Comment: So how to handle that? I need to have that access to the geographical location with the hostname I specify.

Comment: Are you able to navigate to expedia.com.nl manually in a browser inside the same machine?

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha Yes. Because they provide you the links for different locations. And Expedia here is used as an example only. Actually I meant to use different website.